# Rails - maintain params (search history) with remote form when navigating back

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, erb

I've a Rails 5 index with a search form that filters the results.

Said form uses `remote: true` to hit the controller, update the results then uses the relevant `index.js.erb` file to update the results container.

The issue I'm addressing is that clicking a result followed by navigating back doesn't maintain the previous search.

I've fixed this using the following in `index.js.erb`:

```
// new fields to update the history
const url = new URL(window.location);
url.searchParams.set('query', '<%= params[:query] %>');
url.searchParams.set('query_sort', '<%= params[:query_sort] %>');
window.history.pushState(null, null, url);

// existing code to update the results
$('#container').replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'partial') %>");
```

However, this feels convoluted and like there should be a better (inbuilt?) solution.

Does anyone know of the conventional way of achieving this? If not, any ideas on an efficient approach are much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `request.referrer` to get the current browser URL and manipulate this using ruby.

Full code using ruby should be something like this:

**index.js.erb**

```rb
// new fields to update the history
<%
  url = request.referrer
  uri = URI.parse(url)

  query = Rack::Utils.parse_query(uri.query)
  query['query'] = params[:query]
  query['query_sort'] = params[:query_sort]

  uri.query = Rack::Utils.build_query(query)
%>

window.history.pushState(null, null, '<%= uri.to_s %>');

// existing code to update the results
$('#container').replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'partial') %>");
```